# Truffle Console opens truffle(ganache) instead of truffle(development)

Tags: truffle, ganache, console

When I enter `truffle console` it open `truffle(ganache)>` instead of `truffle(development)>`. I think this maybe the reason my program is failing to compile. Are these two the same and is the problem in my program something else?

```
LENOVO@DESKTOP-BGBIAMN MINGW64 ~/eth-todo-list
$ truffle console
truffle(ganache)>
```

Comment: try truffle develop

Answer (score 1):

You can edit that behavior in your truffle-config.js file. That is where the `truffle console` command picks the network it will connect to. In your case ganache network seems to have been set as default/development.

Example of truffle.js file:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

const fs = require('fs');
const secret = fs.readFileSync("./.secret").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
    /**
     * Networks define how you connect to your ethereum client and let you set the
     * defaults web3 uses to send transactions. If you don't specify one truffle
     * will spin up a development blockchain for you on port 9545 when you
     * run `develop` or `test`. You can ask a truffle command to use a specific
     * network from the command line, e.g
     *
     * $ truffle test --network <network-name>
     */

    networks: {
        // Useful for testing. The `development` name is special - truffle uses it by default
        // if it's defined here and no other network is specified at the command line.
        // You should run a client (like ganache-cli, geth or parity) in a separate terminal
        // tab if you use this network and you must also set the `host`, `port` and `network_id`
        // options below to some value.
        //
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
            port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
            network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
        },

        // Ganache test network 
        ganache: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
            port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
            network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
        },
    

        // Another network with more advanced options...
        goerli: {
            network_id: 5,       // Custom network
            gas: 4465030,           // Gas sent with each transaction (default: ~6700000)
            gasPrice: 10000000000,  // 20 gwei (in wei) (default: 100 gwei)
        },

        // Useful for deploying to a public network.
        // NB: It's important to wrap the provider as a function.
        ropsten: {
            provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID`),
            network_id: 3,       // Ropsten's id
            gas: 5500000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
            confirmations: 2,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
            timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
            skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
        }

    },

    // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
    mocha: {
        // timeout: 100000
        reporter:'spec'
        //reporter:'mocha-junit-reporter'
    },

    // Configure your compilers
    compilers: {
        solc: {
            version: "0.8.0",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
            //  docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
            settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
                optimizer: {
                    enabled: false,
                    runs: 200
                },
                evmVersion: "byzantium"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also pick which network you want to connect to by adding "network" parameter to the truffle console command

```
truffle console --network "name of the network"
```

Example:

```
truffle console --network ganache
```

Comment: For me it was always written development, now I know why. Thanks.